# Consume XMLHTTPRequest header

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, header, xmlhttprequest

I created the following request on javascript:

```
this.XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("AgentGUID", AgentGUID);
```

How can I consume it throw C# web service?
the request gets to the following WebService:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mysite.com/WebServices/Agent", Description = "Some description")]
public class AgentService : WebService
{

    [WebMethod(Description = "SomeDesc.", MessageName = "LoginRSA")]
    public LoginResult LoginRSA(string loginId, string password, string tenant)
    {
        // Here I want to consume request header
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you have to look at the following property.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["AgentGUID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` is accessible from an WebService also, so you can use this:

```
var agentGUID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["AgentGUID"];
```

Comment: Local variables should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I voted +1 but I gave the check mark to BitKFu just because he was first.

Comment: Thanks, well I was aware someone answered before me, but I was at few letters before to finish the answer so I really couldn't keep myself not to post it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `this.Context.Request` to access the current request. This contains a `Headers` property.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "SomeDesc.", MessageName = "LoginRSA")]
public LoginResult LoginRSA(string loginId, string password, string tenant)
{
    string agent = this.Context.Request.Headers["AgentGUID"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I voted +1 but I gave the check mark to BitKFu just because he was first.